# Integrating $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\log\left( x^2 + 2 x \sin(\theta) + 1 \right)}{x + 2 \sin(\theta)} d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics

Let $x>0$. I've encountered the following integral:
$$
I(x) \ = \ \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\log\left( x^2 + 2 x \sin(\theta) + 1 \right)}{x + 2 \sin(\theta)} d\theta
$$

Is there a way to integrate this? I've been looking through Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, and I have found some similar integrals but nothing that looks exactly like this. Maybe through a contour integration?

If there is no way to integrate this, is it possible to derive asymptotics for the above $I(x)$ in the limit $x \to \infty$?

Comment: Try $\displaystyle\mathrm{I}'\left(x\right)$.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but I get the following mess which is even worse to deal with: $$I'(x) = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \left[ \frac{2 x + 2 \sin(\theta)}{\left(x + 2 \sin(\theta) \right)\left( x^2 +2 x \sin(\theta) + 1 \right)} - \frac{\log\left( x^2 + 2 x \sin(\theta) + 1 \right)}{\left(x + 2 \sin(\theta)\right)^2}\right] d\theta$$

Comment: Surprising or not, a CAS is able to produce the antiderivative which is just .... a **monster** !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici What is CAS ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas. **C**omputer **A**lgebra **S**ystem. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system

Comment: For the fun of it, use WA anr type **integrate log(x^2+2x sin(t)+1)/(x+2sin(t)) for t**

Comment: the asymptotics for $x\gg1$ are trivial since $x^2\gg2x\sin x\gg1$ in this case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment, a CAS was able to find the antiderivative (the resulting formula is a few pages long !).

The only thing I was able to do is to expand the integrand as a Taylor series built at $t=0$ and then to integrate between the given bounds. Using the expansion to $O(t^{5})$ the result is
$$3840 x^5 \left(x^2+1\right)^4\,I(x)=2 \left(960 \pi  x^4+80 \pi ^3 x^2-\pi ^5 \left(x^2-12\right)\right)
   \left(x^2+1\right)^4 \log \left(x^2+1\right)+\pi ^3 x^2 \left(\pi ^2 \left(3
   x^8-42 x^6-97 x^4-82 x^2-24\right)-80 \left(3 x^2+2\right)
   \left(x^3+x\right)^2\right)$$

Using $x=10^k$ and the above formula, we can compare with the numerical integration. Below are some results for ten significant figures.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation} & \text{integration} & \color{blue} {\text{Maxim's asymptotics}}\\
 1 & 0.7285409898 & 0.7285572863 & \color{blue} {0.7284940770}\\
 2 & 0.1446859930 & 0.1446860624 & \color{blue} {0.1446860611}\\
 3 & 0.02170136876 & 0.02170136887 &\color{blue} { 0.02170136887}\\
 4 & 0.002893513786 & 0.002893513786 & \color{blue} {0.002893513786}\\
 5 & 0.0003616892206 & 0.0003616892206 & \color{blue} {0.0003616892206}\\
 6 & 0.00004340270647 & 0.00004340270647 & \color{blue} {0.00004340270647}
\end{array}
\right)$$ Using the result and expanding again as a Taylor series for infinitely large values of $x$
$$I(x)=\pi \frac {\log(x)} x+O\left(\frac{\log(x)}{x^3}\right)$$

**Edit**

For the evaluation fo the integral, it could be simpler to build a $[1,1]$ Padé approximant  at $t=0$. This will give for the integrand
$$\frac{a +b\, t}{1+c\, t}=\frac b c+\frac{a-\frac b c}{1+c\,t}$$ (easy to integrate) where
$$a=\frac{\log \left(x^2+1\right)}{x}$$
$$b=\frac{\left(x^2+2\right) \log \left(x^2+1\right)-2 x^2}{\left(x^2+1\right)
   \left(\left(x^2+1\right) \log \left(x^2+1\right)-x^2\right)}$$
$$c=\frac{2 \left(x^2+1\right)^2 \log \left(x^2+1\right)-x^2 \left(3 x^2+2\right)}{x
   \left(x^2+1\right) \left(\left(x^2+1\right) \log \left(x^2+1\right)-x^2\right)}$$
This would give 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation} & \text{integration} \\
 1 & 0.7290369069 & 0.7285572863 \\
 2 & 0.1446872219 & 0.1446860624 \\
 3 & 0.02170137072 & 0.02170136887 \\
 4 & 0.002893513788 & 0.002893513786 \\
 5 & 0.0003616892207 & 0.0003616892206 \\
 6 & 0.00004340270647 & 0.00004340270647
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

Concerning the initial Taylor expansion, the problem is a little simpler considering
$$\frac{\log (a+2 b \sin (t))}{b+2 \sin (t)}=\sum_{n=0}^4 c_i \, t^i + O\left(t^5\right)$$ where $a=x^2+1$ and $b=x$. This leads to
$$c_0=\frac{\log (a)}{b}\qquad c_1=\frac{2 \left(b^2-a \log (a)\right)}{a b^2}$$
$$c_2=\frac{4 a^2 \log (a)-2 b^2\left(2 a +b^2\right)}{a^2 b^3}$$
$$c_3=\frac{a^3 \left(b^2-24\right) \log (a)+24 a^2 b^2-(a-12) a b^4+8 b^6}{3 a^3 b^4}$$
$$c_4=\frac{-4 a^4 \left(b^2-12\right) \log (a)-48 a^3 b^2+4 (a-6) a^2 b^4+2 (a-8) a
   b^6-12 b^8}{3 a^4 b^5}$$
Now
$$\int_{-\frac \pi 4}^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{\log (a+2 b \sin (t))}{b+2 \sin (t)}\,dt\approx\frac{\pi}{2}   c_0+\frac{\pi ^3}{96}  c_2+\frac{\pi ^5 }{2560}c_4$$ Going to asymptotics
$$I(x)=\pi\frac{  \log (x)}{x}\left(1+\frac{\pi ^2 \left(80-\pi ^2\right)}{960\, x^2} +\cdots\right)$$

**Update**

After Maxim's answer, I added in blue the value obtained for the integral using jis/her asymptotics. Much better than mine.

Comment: The remainder in the formula for $I(x)$ should be $O(x^{-3} \log x)$.

Comment: @Maxim. You are indeed very correct ! Thanks for pointing out. By the way, have you been able to do something with this integral ? Cheers.

Comment: I've added an answer. The coefficient at $x^{-3} \ln x$ should be $2 (\pi - 2)$. The problem is that when you expand the integrand to higher orders around $t = 0$, you'll get $x^{-3} \ln x$ contributions from higher order terms as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you make the standard substitution $\theta = 2 \arctan u$, the integrand becomes
$$\frac {\ln \frac {P(u)} {Q(u)}} {R(u)},$$
where $P, Q, R$ are quadratic polynomials. Factoring the polynomials and formally expanding the logarithm reduces the indefinite integral to a sum of integrals of the form
$$\int \frac {\ln u} {u + a} du =
\ln u \ln \left( 1 + \frac u a \right) +
 \operatorname{Li}_2 \left( - \frac u a \right).$$
With the natural choice of the factors, the antiderivative will be continuous in $u$ for large positive $x$, yielding a closed form for the definite integral.

To obtain the asymptotic, you can simply expand the integrand around $x = \infty$ and integrate term by term:
$$\frac {\ln (x^2 + 2 x \sin \theta + 1)} {x + 2 \sin \theta} = \\
\frac {2 \ln x} x - \frac {4 \ln x \sin t - 2 \sin t } {x^2} +
 \frac {8 \ln x \sin^2 t + \cos 2 t - 4 \sin^2 t} {x^3} + o(x^{-3}), \\
I(x) = \frac {\pi \ln x} x +
 \frac {2 (\pi - 2) \ln x - \pi + 3} {x^3} + o(x^{-3}).$$

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. You are totally right for the asymptotics; your approach is much better than mine.

Comment: What is intresting is that $2(\pi-2)\approx 2.28319$ while $\frac{\pi ^3 \left(80-\pi ^2\right)}{960}\approx 2.26509 $ and that $\pi-3= 0.14159$.

Comment: Hoping that you don't mind, I added to my answer the value of the integral using the asymptotics you provided. Impressive !

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ sufficiently large, and putting all in the form

$$2\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{\log(x)}{x}\cdot \frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{1+2\sin(\theta)/x}+\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{\log\left(1 + 1/x (2\sin(\theta) + 1/x) \right)}{x }\cdot \frac{\textrm{d}\theta}{1+2\sin(\theta)/x} $$
combined with the power series of $\log(1+x)$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+x}$, and integrating termwise, we arrive, for example, at the asymptotical behaviour

$$I(x)\approx\pi\frac{\log(x)}{x}+\frac{2(\pi-2)\log(x)+3-\pi}{x^3}+\frac{12(3\pi-8)\log(x)-21\pi+64}{6x^5}.$$

Comment: Using this,we almost get the exact value of the integral. For $x=10$, we get $0.7285564014$ and for $x=100$, we get $0.1446860624$.